# FCM cloud function typescript to devices

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to use this data structure to send FCM to devices?  When the document is created the function is triggered but I get an error "token must be non empty string or array".  Can my code be fixed or is what i'm trying to do not possible?

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();
const fcm = admin.messaging();


export const sendToDevice = functions.firestore
  .document('messages/{userid}')
  .onCreate(async snapshot => {


    const querySnapshot = await db
      .collection('messages')
      .doc('userid')
      .collection('tokens')

      .get();

    const token = querySnapshot.docs.map(token => token.id);

    const payload: admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
      notification: {
        title: 'Emergency',
        body: `Alert`,
      //  icon: 'your-icon-url',
        click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
      }
    };

    return fcm.sendToDevice(token, payload);
  });
```

[image: db structure]

Can cloud functions send FCM to devices using the on create method with a database structure like this?  Or does the document have to only contain tokens and nothing else?

Comment: I haven't been able to get it to work.  There may be a way of looping thru the document map, and creating a new database with only the tokens, but this is beyond my ability.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to modify your code to get the message on my device. See my comments in the code for more details:

```
const payload: admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
      notification: {
        title: 'Emergency',
        body: `Alert`,
        // icon: 'your-icon-url',
        // click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK' // ** do not put it here
      },
      data: { click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK', message: 'Your MSG' } // Use this data section
    };
```